# Learning Python/unittest. Second test won't pass, not sure why? Below are both files on single page

Tags: python

First test works but second test fails

```
"""A collection of functions for working with cities."""

def city_country(city,state,population=''):
    """Return a string representing a city-state pair."""

    if population:
        output = f'{city} {state} {population}'
    else:
        output = f'{city} {state}'
        return output
```

```
import unittest
from city_functions import city_country

class CityTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests for 'city_functions.py'."""

    def test_formatt(self):
        """Does a simple city and state pair work?"""
        city_info = city_country('hemet','cali')
        self.assertEqual(city_info,'hemet cali')


    def test_formatt_population(self):
        """Can I include a population argument?"""
        city_info = city_country('hemet','cali', 'population=5000')
        self.assertEqual(city_country,'hemet cali population 5000')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: It's not clear why you think the `=` from the third argument would be dropped.

Comment: Your second assert equals is comparing city_country not city_info (i.e. the function with a string)

Comment: The empty string has a falsy value, so this is correct (albeit `None` is probably a better choice for the default argument). The issue was with how the function was being called.

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues with your code.

---

The first is an indentation error:

```
if population:
    output = f'{city} {state} {population}'
else:
    output = f'{city} {state}'
    return output
```

does not return a string if the `if` branch is executed, because the `return output` statement is inside the `else` branch. Because of this, your function can return `None`.

To resolve, shift the `return output` statement over one indent to the left.

```
if population:
    output = f'{city} {state} {population}'
else:
    output = f'{city} {state}'
return output
```

---

The second issue is that `city_country('hemet','cali', 'population=5000')`. inserts the string literal `'population=5000'` into your output. That causes an output of `'hemet cali population=5000'` as opposed to `'hemet cali population 5000'` (with an undesired equals sign).

To resolve, make the third parameter `'population 5000'`. Your function call in the second test case should look like this:

```
city_country('hemet','cali', 'population 5000')
```

---

The third issue is that you're using `assertEqual` between a function and a string, since `city_country` is a function -- this assertion will always fail, because the types of the arguments are different.

Your second assert should look like:

```py
self.assertEqual(city_info,'hemet cali population 5000')
```

as opposed to

```py
self.assertEqual(city_country,'hemet cali population 5000')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried to indent and when I do I get indentation.

Comment: Shift to the left, not to the right.

Comment: Same, indentation errors despite the direction I shift.

Comment: Oh, there's a second issue with your code. I'll edit.